# Current Location in Map fragment Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, currentlocation

I'm new to Android Development and I am trying to development an application which will display a google map with the users current location. I have been sucessful in incorporating the map in and adding markers but having issues with getting the current location. I have added location permissions in.

activity_location.xml

```
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Android Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.alicearmstrong.coffeysloyaltyprojectv1">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
   <activity
        android:name=".NavigationMainOwner"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_navigation_main_owner" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/api_map_key" />
....
```

LocationFragment.java

```
public class LocationFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private LocationViewModel locationViewModel;
    private GoogleMap gMap;
    private MapView mapView;
    private Location currentLocation;
    private int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;


    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        locationViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of( this ).get( LocationViewModel.class );
        View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_location_customer, container, false );

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated( view, savedInstanceState );

        mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById( R.id.map );
        if (mapView != null)
        {
            mapView.onCreate( null );
            mapView.onResume();
            mapView.getMapAsync( this );
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) 
    {
        MapsInitializer.initialize( getContext() );
        gMap = googleMap;
        LatLng coffeys = new LatLng( 54.572720, -5.959151 );
        gMap.addMarker( new MarkerOptions().position( coffeys ).title( "Coffey's Butchers" ) );
        gMap.moveCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom( coffeys, 12 ) );

    }

    private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // GPS may be turned off
            if (location == null) {
                return;
            }

            Double lat = location.getLatitude();
            Double lng = location.getLongitude();

            currentLocation = location;
            Toast.makeText( getActivity(), "Updated Location: " + lat + lng, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

        }
    };


    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    public boolean checkLocationPermission()
    {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION )
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {


            // Asking user if explanation is needed
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale( getActivity(),
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ))
            {
                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                requestPermissions( new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE
                );



            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                requestPermissions( new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE );

            }
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated! Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Maps default current location setting it with `gMap.setmylocationenabled(true)`. Or you can use `moveCamera(CameraUpdate update)` when getting your current location in your locationListener.